# graphql @skip @include directives cannot query field

Tags: graphql, graphql-schema

I want to use graphql `@include` and/or `@skip` directives for compatibility between frontend and backend.
Assume backend and frontend have a differing schema:
backend:

```
type Foo {
  someOldProp: Int!
}
```

frontend:

```
type Foo {
  someOldProp: Int! @deprecated(reason: "Use someNewProp instead")
  someNewProp: Int!
}
```

now in frontend I define following fragment:

```
fragment FooFragment on Foo {
  someOldProp @skip(if: $hasNew)
  someNewProp @include(if: $hasNew)
}
```

When passing `$hasNew` as `false` in a query, the fragment should be resolved as:

```
fragment FooFragment on Foo {
  someOldProp
}
```

which would be a valid fragment to be used with the backend schema above.
However, even in this case our graphql service complains about
`Cannot query field 'someOldProp' on type 'Foo'`.

Reading [the spec](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec--skip), it's not totally clear to me whether this is a bug in our graphql implementation (which should not attempt accessing a field when `@include`/`@skip` exclude the field),
or whether these directives are only to be used when all underlying fields are available, but when a subset of them is not needed by the client.

In the latter case a graphql implementation would be free to query a field at first, and only erase it before handing it to the client which would explain the error-message.

Does anyone have some insight?